# Do until or Do while?

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone please help me with the below. i am trying to automate this using a formula in column P on the basis of ccy written in column A. for example: if ccy = ARS, then formula in column P should be =1/24*5
if ccy = BRL then formula in column p should be =1/24*6 and formula should xldown till the last available row

should I use Do while or Do until ?

[image]

Comment: Do until condition is false = do while condition is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Each Next Loop Solution

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub updateByCriteria()
    
    ' Define Constants.
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 5
    Const srcCol As String = "A"
    Const tgtCol As String = "P"
    Dim Criteria As Variant
    Dim Formulas As Variant
    Criteria = Array("ARS", "BRL")       ' add more...
    Formulas = Array("=1/245", "=1/246") ' add more...
    
    ' Define Source Column Range.
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' Define worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    ' Calculate Last Non-Empty Row.
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, srcCol).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Define Source Column Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, srcCol), ws.Cells(LastRow, srcCol))
    
    ' Prepare to write to Target Column Range.
     
    ' Calculate Column Offset.
    Dim ColOffset As Long
    ColOffset = ws.Columns(tgtCol).Column - ws.Columns(srcCol).Column
    
    ' Declare variables.
    Dim CurPos As Variant ' Current Position
    Dim cel As Range      ' Current Cell Range
    
    ' Write formulas to Target Column Range.
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Iterate the cell ranges in Source Range.
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        ' Check if Current Cell Range in Source Column Range is not empty.
        If Not IsEmpty(cel) Then
            ' Try to find the value in Current Cell Range in Criteria Array
            ' and write the position to Current Position
            CurPos = Application.Match(cel, Criteria, 0)
            ' Check if value in Current Cell Range has been found
            ' in Criteria Array.
            If Not IsError(CurPos) Then
                ' Write formula from Formulas Array to current Target Cell
                ' Range, using Current Position in Criteria Array.
                cel.Offset(, ColOffset).Formula = _
                  Application.Index(Formulas, CurPos)
            End If
        End If
    Next cel
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform user.
    
    MsgBox "Formulas copied.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thx VBasic it worked just one thing, in case if I wish to use customized formulas  like p5 = K4+L5, P6 = K4+L6, P7= K4+L7 and so on for ARS currency, and for BRL P15 = K14+ L15, P16=K14+L16, P17= K14+ L17 and so on in short i have customised formulas for each set of currency (further bifurcated to subset rows of each ccy). what changes would you prefer in the code.

Comment: Instead of `=1/245` and `=1/246` input the formulas you need. Then see what has happened. If it doesn't work as expected and you cannot figure out what to change, just ask another question with the details about what you are getting and what you are expecting. Include the code of course.

Comment: I guess you could use something like `=K$4+L5` and `K$14+L15`.

Comment: Yes vbasic you are right, i have tried the same approach and it worked. Just one last which is bothering is there is one currency RUB which has 6 set of rows but i need to use the formula on first 4 rows only and leave the last two rows as it is and move to other currency. By any chance is it possible?

Comment: any help on the above?

Comment: It would be best that you post another question including the code, so we can see how you implemented the formula. Include a description what is wrong with it. Feel free to post a link to the question in these comments, so I can find it. But you might get another answer from someone else, too.

Answer (score 0):

`Do while` will loop while the condition is True and `Do Until` will loop until the condition is True, if you adjust your conditions both can be made work.